# Adding a java.awt.frame to a vaadin layout

Tags: java, eclipse, awt, vaadin

I'm working on a vaadin page, but one of the elements I want to put in my VerticalLayout is a java.awt.Frame. Is there a way to do this in vaadin?

Comment: do you need something, that behaves like a window or really some awt stuff like an applet embedded?

Comment: I'm trying to add a TeeChart (com.steema.teechart.TChart) to a vaadin VerticalLayout. I'm aware of vaadin charts, but they're limited, so I'm trying to see if I can use TeeChart as a substitute by adding it to a vaadin page.

Comment: you can not use stock swing/awt components with vaadin.  reading their homepage, you could use the html5/javascript version.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, you can't use Swing/AWT stuff in Vaadin since it will be converted to Javascript and DOM to be used in a browser.

If you get a hold on the JS file TeeChart uses you can basically implement a custom client-side widget that will use it.

Take the [basic demo here](http://www.steema.com/files/public/teechart/html5/v2012.12.14.1.4/demos/) what you have to take care of is that there is a <canvas> tag to render the content in and that the draw() is called at a phase when Vaadin is done creating the surrounding DOM structure.

Please have a look at [this tutorial](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Integrating+a+JavaScript+component+) to get an idea on how to wrap a JavaScript library to a Vaadin component.

Comment: I guess I'm confued about how the vaadin class talks to the js file. What would I need to write for this code to execute <script type="text/javascript">

function draw() {
  // Create a chart with the specified canvas:
  var Chart1=new Tee.Chart("canvas");

  Chart1.addSeries(new Tee.Line([5,3,2,7,1]) );
  Chart1.addSeries(new Tee.Line([4,4,8,2,9]) ).visible=true;

  Chart1.series.items[0].format.stroke.size=3;

  Chart1.axes.left.format.stroke.fill="red";

  Chart1.title.text="TeeChart for JavaScript";
  Chart1.title.format.font.style="18px Verdana";
  Chart1.draw();
}
</script>